# How to clear the content of multiple files in UNIX

Tags: file, unix

I often have to clear content of all files in a directory (i.e. Apache Tomcat logs). I am using UNIX's redirection operator  this way:

`> catalina.out`

How can I apply it to all files in the current directory (to clear all logs)?

I tried `> *.*` but it doesn't make sense. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little loop can make it:

```
for file in * .*       <---- * for normal files // .* for hidden files
do
  echo "clearing $file"
  > $file
done
```

Comment: `*.*` will only list those files whose names contain a `.`  Using `*` will generate a larger list.

Comment: Oh, yes, I guess the best way is to use `for file in * .*` so that all normal files (`*`) and hidden ones (`.*`) will be included. Will update accordingly, thanks @WilliamPursell